# AudioKit blocking

Tags: ios, avaudiosession, audiokit

Looking at this bit of code below as I setup an AudioKit session which is monitoring amplitude and frequency.

At the same time, I try to play a custom sound with a local notification, but it seems the configuration below blocks the sound playing.

AudioKit.start() is the culprit for blocking my local notification sound playing.

Any suggestions on how to solve this?

```
init() {
    AKSettings.audioInputEnabled = true
    mic = AKMicrophone()
    tracker = AKFrequencyTracker(mic)
    silence = AKBooster(tracker, gain: 0)

    AKSettings.sampleRate = AudioKit.engine.inputNode.inputFormat(forBus: 0).sampleRate
    AKSettings.bufferLength = .medium
}

func startAudioAnalysis() {
    silence.start()
    tracker.start()
    mic.start()

    AudioKit.output = silence

    do {
        try AudioKit.start()
        try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setCategory(.playAndRecord, mode: .default, options: [])
    } catch {
        AKLog("AudioKit did not start! \(error)")
    }

    startUpdates()
}
```